# How to use emit and props properly in Nuxt3 Composition Api

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I want to use emit and props in Nuxtjs3, but not sure, what i am doing wrong here.

in My project, i need to find airport data at a lot of pages, so i created a airportsearch component.

this is inside
components/AirportSearch.vue

```html
<template>
      <AutoComplete
        class="ttc-w-full ttc-h-12"
        v-model="AirportData"
        :suggestions="airports"
        @complete="getairports($event)"
        field="name"
        placeholder="Search Pickup Location"
        forceSelection
        @item-select="Update"
      >
        <template #item="slotProps">
          <div
            style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between"
            class="ttc-font-bold ttc-text-md"
          >
            {{ slotProps.item.name }}
            <span class="ttc-font-normal ttc-text-xs">
              {{ slotProps.item.code }}
            </span>
          </div>
        </template>
      </AutoComplete>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const { apiUrl } = useRuntimeConfig();
const airports = ref([]);
const emit = defineEmits(["submit"])

const props = defineProps(['AirportData']);

const getairports = useDebounce(async (event) => {
  const { data } = await useFetch(`${apiUrl}/airports/find`, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      aptsearchkey: event.query,
    }),
  });
  airports.value = data.value;
}, 500);


function Update(event) {
    emit("submit", props.AirportData);
}

</script>
```

this is another component inside components folder
TaxiSearchForm.vue

```html
<template>
 <div>
   <AirportSearch 
      :AirportData="pickuppoint"
      @submit="handleUpdate"
   />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
 import {ref} from 'vue'
        
 const airportTransferData = useCookie("airportTransferData", {
   maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
 });
        
 let pickuppoint = ref();
        
 function handleUpdate(pickuppoint) {
         pickuppoint.value = pickuppoint;
 };
    
onMounted(() => {
   if (airportTransferData.value) {
      pickuppoint.value = airportTransferData.value.pickuppoint;
    }
 });
        
</script>
```

I am not able to pass data from AirportSearch Component to TaxiSearchForm.

When i Select dropdown in AirportSearch, I see that AirportData Prop is getting populated. but I want same Data to be passed to var pickuppoint in TaxiSearchForm.

this is sample of response from api in AirportSearch.vue

```js
const airports = [
    {
        "aptid": "1439",
        "code": "DXB",
        "name": "Dubai Intl Airport",
        "cityCode": "DXB",
        "cityName": "Dubai",
        "countryName": "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES",
        "countryCode": "AE",
        "continent_id": null,
        "timezone": "4",
        "lat": "25.252778",
        "lon": "55.364444",
        "city": "true",
        "id": "6135ee7e91649f157edff402"
    },
    {
        "aptid": "3101",
        "code": "XNB",
        "name": "Dubai Bus Station Airport",
        "cityCode": "DXB",
        "cityName": "Dubai",
        "countryName": "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES",
        "countryCode": "AE",
        "continent_id": null,
        "timezone": "3",
        "lat": "0",
        "lon": "0",
        "city": "false",
        "id": "6135ee7e91649f157edffa80"
    },
    {
        "aptid": "3475",
        "code": "DWC",
        "name": "Al Maktoum International Airport",
        "cityCode": "DXB",
        "cityName": "Dubai",
        "countryName": "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES",
        "countryCode": "AE",
        "continent_id": null,
        "timezone": "4",
        "lat": "24.898504",
        "lon": "55.143231",
        "city": "false",
        "id": "6135ee7e91649f157edffbf6"
    },
    {
        "aptid": "7609",
        "code": "SHJ",
        "name": "Sharjah Airport",
        "cityCode": "DXB",
        "cityName": "Dubai",
        "countryName": "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES",
        "countryCode": "AE",
        "continent_id": null,
        "timezone": "4",
        "lat": "25.328575",
        "lon": "55.51715",
        "city": "false",
        "id": "6135ee7f91649f157ee00c1c"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `handleUpdate()` argument (`pickuppoint`) shadows the outer `ref` of the same name, so the function incorrectly modifies its argument instead of the `ref`:

```js
let pickuppoint = ref()

function handleUpdate(pickuppoint) {
   //  this is the function argument, not the outer ref
  pickuppoint.value = pickuppoint
}
```

The fix is to make the names different. For instance, rename the function argument:

```js
let pickuppoint = ref()

function handleUpdate(newPickuppoint) {
  pickuppoint.value = newPickuppoint
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-emitting-data?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FTaxiSearchForm.vue)